# Avoid duplicates on self join

Tags: mysql, query, self-join

Given the following table *my_table* :

```
my_column
------
A
B
C
D
```

I would like to be able to join on itself but without duplicate pairs like so:

```
-- SELECT a.*, b.* FROM my_table a JOIN my_table b ON a.my_column <> b.my_column; 
-- something like so but without the duplicate pairs

a.my_column | b.my_column
------------+-----------
A           | B
A           | C
A           | D
B           | C
B           | D
C           | D
```

How should I tackle this in SQL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table a
JOIN my_table b ON a.my_column < b.my_column
```

Comment: woow that is awesome